# center image vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css, alignment

I typically use content above a `div` to push everything down. This project needs one single image centered horizontally and vertically with nothing else.

My searches turned up lots of results, but I've mixed and matched to no avail.  Care to help?

Here's the simple HTML

```
<div id="entpa">
    <section id="mainContAPos">
    </section>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS

```css
body{
  background-color: #0D0D0D;
}

#entpa{
  position: absolute;
}

#mainContAPos{
  position: fixed;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-image: url('frontpage1366.png');
  width: 1366px;
  height: 768px;
  border: 8px solid #FFF4CF;
  border-radius: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

HTML (no changes)

```
 <div id="entpa">
    <section id="mainContAPos"></section>
 </div>
```

CSS

```css
html, body { height: 100%; }

#entpa {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center; /* center child div horizontally (in this case) */
     align-items: center; /* center child div vertically (in this case) */
     height: 100%;
     /* position: absolute; REMOVE; no need for this */
 }

 #mainContAPos{
     /* vertical-align: middle; REMOVE; no need for this */
     background-image: url('frontpage1366.png');
     width: 1366px;
     height: 768px;
     border: 8px solid #FFF4CF;
     border-radius: 16px;
  }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qxmLk1j6/

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex).*

For more information about **CSS Flexbox** visit:

- [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
- [What the Flexbox?!](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLu8EoSxDXHP7xj_y6NIAhy0wuCd4uVdid) (video tutorial)

Comment: That's clean.  Nice.  Thanks.  A TON.

Comment: I have yet to see IE pop up on analytics more than 5 times a month for the site this is for.  

Thanks for the new info to look into, "flexbox"...

Comment: `html, body { 
  background-color: #0D0D0D;
  background-image: url('noise.png');
  height: 99%; 
}`

I changed 100% to 99% and it got rid of the vertical scroll bar...  Thanks for the links.